# Run a function after Array.map

Tags: javascript, arrays, async-await

I am want to run a async function once the Array.map completes the execution.

I am making async calls in the map method in a function updateMaterials , my objective is to call the addDataToDB once the updateMaterials completes the execution.

Function 1 : updateMaterials

```
 const updateMaterials = recipeRawMaterials => {
    recipeRawMaterials.map((item, index) => {
      updateRawMaterialsDB(item._id, item.rate, index);
    });
  };
```

Async function: updateRawMaterialsDB

```
const updateRawMaterialsDB = async (id, rate, index) => {
    console.log(state.recipeRawMaterials);
    const body = JSON.stringify({
      rate
    });

    console.log(body);

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/JSON'
      }
    };

    const res = await axios.put(`/api/v1/rawMaterial/${id}`, body, config);

   
  };
```

```
 const addDataToDB = async (recipeName, recipeRawMaterials) => {
   

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/JSON'
      }
    };

    const res = await axios.post('/api/v1/basicRecipe', body, config);
    setLoading();
    
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more common approach is to use @Ubeyt Demir's answer that collects the async calls into a collection of promises that then trigger a final call when those promises have been resolved.

This answer uses a feature in ES2018 in which you can use async iterators. This is nicely laid out in this ECMA proposal https://2ality.com/2016/10/asynchronous-iteration.html

So using;

```
for await (const asyncItem of asyncCollection) {
  console.log(asyncItem);
}
console.log("done")
```

We will print the "done" statement when the iterator of async promises have been resolved.
Using this in your code it will look like:

```
items = [{_id: 1, rate: 2, index: 0},
{_id: 2, rate: 3, index: 2}, 
{_id: 3, rate: 4, index: 3}, 
{_id: 4, rate: 5, index: 4}, 
{_id: 5, rate: 6, index: 5},]

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
const updateRawMaterialsDB = async (id, rate, index) => {
    const body = JSON.stringify({
        rate
    });
    console.log(body);
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/JSON'
        }
    };
    //return axios.put(`/api/v1/rawMaterial/${id}`, body, config);
    return sleep(2000);
};
async function addDataToDB(recipeName, recipeRawMaterials) {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/JSON'
        }
    };
    //const res = await axios.post('/api/v1/basicRecipe', body, config);
    //setLoading();
    console.log('All done');
};

async function updateMaterials(recipeRawMaterials) {
    const arrayofPromises = recipeRawMaterials.map((item, index) => {
        updateRawMaterialsDB(item._id, item.rate, index);
    });
    for await (const item of arrayofPromises) {
        console.log("item done");
    }
    addDataToDB('something', recipeRawMaterials)
}
updateMaterials(items);
```

Comment: This is stylish! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can return promises in map and after Promise.all fulfilled you can call addDataToDB function

```
const updateMaterials = recipeRawMaterials => {
   const promises =  recipeRawMaterials.map((item, index) => updateRawMaterialsDB(item._id, item.rate, index));
   Promise.all(promises).then(()=>{
       // addDataToDB 
   })
   .catch(e=>{
       //
   })
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than waiting for each `Promise` to complete you should convert `recipeRawMaterials` into array of promises which would be passed to `Promise.all` which accepts array of Promises, and returns a single one.

```
const updateMaterials = async recipeRawMaterials => await Promise.all(
  recipeRawMaterials.map(({ _id, rate }, index) => updateRawMaterialsDB(_id, rate, index))
);
```

Comment: Hi Rafi ..Thanks for your feedback..How do I make a call to AddDataToDB function once the promises are resolved..

Comment: looking at your code it doesn't seem like `updateMaterials ` returns any value

Comment: I am just making an API request in updateMaterials would that have impact on promise.all implementation..

Comment: no it's all right  (I thought you need the result for the next call)

Comment: just call `addDataToDB ` right below the above code as following : `await addDataToDB (...)`

Comment: and make sure your run all the above code in `async`  context

Comment: Sorry Rafi..If I understand correctly both these functions need to be called in separate async function

Comment: are you calling these two functions from global scope or they are being called by another function?

Comment: They are being called by another function I am calling these 2 in submit function..Objective is to complete the updateMaterials first and then complete the AddDataToDB

Comment: so the calling function has to be `async` as well and so on, if you opt for `async-await` syntax

Comment: Sure..Will try this approach..Thank you for you time..